# How to redirect https file to http file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect all page from https to http using this code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://aplauz.media.pl/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It works!

I want to redirect specific file https to http in the same time.

```
Redirect 301 /aktualnosci/155-rusza-kampania-promujaca-w-polsce-rosji-i-chinach/ http://aplauz.media.pl/blog/rusza-kampania-promujaca-w-polsce-rosji-chinach/
```

It works as well!

**BUT NEVER BOTH because browser inform me about double redirection.
Anyone can help me?**

Comment: I haven't still got what are you exactly asking and what is working and what not

Comment: It's simple: both redirections not working. 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://aplauz.media.pl/$1 [R=301,L]
Redirect 301 /aktualnosci/155-rusza-kampania-promujaca-w-polsce-rosji-i-chinach/ http://aplauz.media.pl/blog/rusza-kampania-promujaca-w-polsce-rosji-chinach/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^aktualnosci/155-rusza-kampania-promujaca-w-polsce-rosji-i-chinach/ http://aplauz.media.pl/blog/rusza-kampania-promujaca-w-polsce-rosji-chinach/ [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://aplauz.media.pl%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NE,L]
```

i.e. keep specific redirect rule before generic catch-all rule.